# Jquery Scroll Up

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mousehover, onhover

I was editing my Jquery Scroll Up script, it was working perfect but I found the errors when I was trying to change image on hover, this my Blog

and this problematic part of my scroll script

```
    controlHTML: '<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-onAd5CVV5QM/UBzbWeBr88I/AAAAAAAAACI/TPBsgVOiEzg/s1600/arrowhover.png" style="width: 55px; height: 54px; " />',
```

I wana change this image

**http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-onAd5CVV5QM/UBzbWeBr88I/AAAAAAAAACI/TPBsgVOiEzg/s1600/arrowhover.png**

with this image

**http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-onAd5CVV5QM/UBzbWeBr88I/AAAAAAAAACI/TPBsgVOiEzg/s1600/arrow.png**

only on hover,

**Note:**
Well I know how to change image on mouseover in HTML & Jquery, but that wasnt work in this case, I think due to controlling HTML in Script tags, due you know how to fix it??? or if u have any other better script for scroll up in Jquery?? please please give it to me if u have... :)

I'm using this script to change image on hover, its working but not works here!!

```
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ab63W-gTgs8/UBzbU0TauoI/AAAAAAAAACA/TCVHz200nU4/s1600/arrowhover.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-onAd5CVV5QM/UBzbWeBr88I/AAAAAAAAACI/TPBsgVOiEzg/s1600/arrow.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ab63W-gTgs8/UBzbU0TauoI/AAAAAAAAACA/TCVHz200nU4/s1600/arrowhover.png'" style="width: 55px; height: 54px; " />
```

This is my whole Scroll Up script, If u wana review it..

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var scrolltotop={ 
    //startline: Integer. Number of pixels from top of doc scrollbar is scrolled before showing control 
    //scrollto: Keyword (Integer, or "Scroll_to_Element_ID"). How far to scroll document up when control is clicked on (0=top). 
    setting: {startline:100, scrollto: 0, scrollduration:1000, fadeduration:[500, 100]},
    controlHTML: '<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-onAd5CVV5QM/UBzbWeBr88I/AAAAAAAAACI/TPBsgVOiEzg/s1600/arrowhover.png" style="width: 55px; height: 54px; " />', //HTML for control, which is auto wrapped in DIV w/ ID="topcontrol" 
    controlattrs: {offsetx:50, offsety:50}, //offset of control relative to right/ bottom of window corner 
    anchorkeyword: '#top', //Enter href value of HTML anchors on the page that should also act as "Scroll Up" links
    state: {isvisible:false, shouldvisible:false},
    scrollup:function(){ 
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport) //if control is positioned using JavaScript 
            this.$control.css({opacity:0}) //hide control immediately after clicking it 
        var dest=isNaN(this.setting.scrollto)? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto) 
        if (typeof dest=="string" && jQuery('#'+dest).length==1) //check element set by string exists 
            dest=jQuery('#'+dest).offset().top 
        else 
            dest=0 
        this.$body.animate({scrollTop: dest}, this.setting.scrollduration); 
    },
    keepfixed:function(){ 
        var $window=jQuery(window) 
        var controlx=$window.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx 
        var controly=$window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety 
        this.$control.css({left:controlx+'px', top:controly+'px'}) 
    },
    togglecontrol:function(){ 
        var scrolltop=jQuery(window).scrollTop() 
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport) 
            this.keepfixed() 
        this.state.shouldvisible=(scrolltop>=this.setting.startline)? true : false 
        if (this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible){ 
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:1}, this.setting.fadeduration[0]) 
            this.state.isvisible=true 
        } 
        else if (this.state.shouldvisible==false && this.state.isvisible){ 
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:0}, this.setting.fadeduration[1]) 
            this.state.isvisible=false 
        } 
    }, 

    init:function(){ 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            var mainobj=scrolltotop 
            var iebrws=document.all 
            mainobj.cssfixedsupport=!iebrws || iebrws && document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //not IE or IE7+ browsers in standards mode 
            mainobj.$body=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body') 
            mainobj.$control=$('<div id="topcontrol">'+mainobj.controlHTML+'</div>') 
                .css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', bottom:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'pointer'}) 
                .attr({title:'Scroll Back to Top'}) 
                .click(function(){mainobj.scrollup(); return false}) 
                .appendTo('body') 
            if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && mainobj.$control.text()!='') //loose check for IE6 and below, plus whether control contains any text 
                mainobj.$control.css({width:mainobj.$control.width()}) //IE6- seems to require an explicit width on a DIV containing text 
            mainobj.togglecontrol() 
            $('a[href="' + mainobj.anchorkeyword +'"]').click(function(){ 
                mainobj.scrollup() 
                return false 
            }) 
            $(window).bind('scroll resize', function(e){ 
                mainobj.togglecontrol() 
            }) 
        }) 
    } 
}
scrolltotop.init()
</script>
```

Comment: no. i dont have any bugs reported in console / firebug!

Comment: it works perfect in simple JQuery, but not works here!!